# Android / Separating navigation drawer from home page activity overlaps content

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, layout-inflater, android-inflate, setcontentview

I tried to separate navigation drawer from home page activity for common use in all other activities.
However, in doing so, when I tried to replace

```
setContentView(R.layout.home);
```

in Home.java by

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, null, false);
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.addView(contentView, 0);
```

the contents in the home page activity overlap with each other and the list items become no longer clickable.

[image]

How can this issue be fixed? Where am I going wrong? Please help out.

Full source code is available at:

https://bitbucket.org/pradeep-melorra/melorra-android-native/src/development/app/src/main/java/com/melorra/nativeapp/Home.java

You can also feel free to refer to other files within the same project itself.

Comment: Never mind that removing `drawer.addView(contentView, 0);` from the code seemed to fix this issue. Not sure what this statement is supposed to do.

Comment: Making use of R.layout.activity (Android Studio's default R.layout.content_main Navigation Drawer activity) or R.layout.home (Android Studio's default R.layout.activity_main Navigation Drawer activity) does not seem to make any difference. Why?

Comment: If I make use of same navigation drawer in other activities, will making use of R.layout.home (Android Studio's default R.layout.content_main Navigation Drawer activity) gets home page activity's content to be reflected in other activities as well but making use of R.layout.activity (Android Studio's default R.layout.activity_main Navigation Drawer activity) does not?

Comment: Why does making use of the statement `drawer.addView(contentView, 0);` collapse the linear layout inside of scroll view and then cause by user interface items to be overlapped over one another?